# Swift JSONDecoder decode(type:from) does not recognize my data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a data model that conforms to Codable protocal, whose components all conform to Codable protocal.

```
class FMS_UserRelate : Codable {

//MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("FMS_UserRelate.plist")

// MARK: Properties
var consumers: [FMS_Consumer]
var userId: String

//MARK: Initialization
init?(consumers: [FMS_Consumer], userId: String) {
    .
    .
    .

    // Initialize stored properties.
    .
    .
    .
}

// MARK: Codable
enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case consumers
    case userId
}
}
```

In my app I save the data to the disk and load it later. I use NSKeyedArchiver and JSON Encoder/Decoder for this purpose.

Here is what I use for saving. It works fine.

```
    let je = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try? je.encode(userRelate)
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(jsonData as! Data, toFile: FMS_UserRelate.ArchiveURL.path)
```

However when I try JSONDecoder.decode(), the code does not recognize my second input parameter with inline casting. It would work fine if I do the casting to `Data` beforehand. I can't think of any cause of this. I am using Xcode 10.1 with Swift 4.2.

[image: screenshot showing inline casting does not work well with JSON decoder]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` in conjunction with the `Codable` protocol. `NSKeyedArchiver` belongs to `NSCoding` which is another story.

Just write the encoded data

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(userRelate)
    try jsonData.write(to: FMS_UserRelate.ArchiveURL)
} catch { print(error) }
```

and read it back (the function hands over the potential errors)

```
private func loadUserRelateUsingCodable() throws -> FMS_UserRelate {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: FMS_UserRelate.ArchiveURL)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(FMS_UserRelate.self, from: jsonData)
}
```

Note:

**Never** ignore `Encoding`/`Decoding` errors!